# python regex in string commande

Tags: python, regex, networking, wifi

Hi I'm new to python and regex. 
the task I'm trying to accomplish is extract informations from a string: here is the code

```
import subprocess
import re

available = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show network mode=bssid',stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
print(available)
```

the output is a string that is like this:

```
Interface name : Wi-Fi 2 
There are 15 networks currently visible. 

SSID 1 : Rezalitchderk
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP 
    BSSID 1                 : 62:f1:89:7c:71:d1
         Signal             : 91%  
         Radio type         : 802.11n
         Channel            : 11 
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54

    SSID 2 : HUAWEI Mate 10 lite
        Network type            : Infrastructure
        Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
        Encryption              : CCMP 
        BSSID 1                 : 1c:15:1f:3f:87:f9
             Signal             : 82%  
             Radio type         : 802.11n
             Channel            : 11 
             Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
             Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

now I want with regex to retrieve everything after ":"

so I tried this `data= re.findall(r':(.*)', available)`

but the result is not quite what I want it is not in order : [result of the regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e8LV.png)

the regex result should be: wi-fi 2, Rezalchiderk, Infrastructure, Wpa2-Personal ....

How can I have the results in the correct order ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. It doesn't match the code you posted; there is no "yournetwork" anywhere in the input, but somehow it's there in the output. Please post a [mcve] if you want to know what's wrong with your code.

Comment: The reason is not your regex, it works just fine. Could it be that you have executed the `netsh` - command a second time?

Comment: yes the regex works :) I made I rerun it a second time

Answer (score 0):

By using **string.split** method

```
A = '''Interface name : Wi-Fi 2 
There are 15 networks currently visible. 

SSID 1 : Rezalitchderk
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP 
    BSSID 1                 : 62:f1:89:7c:71:d1
         Signal             : 91%  
         Radio type         : 802.11n
         Channel            : 11 
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54

    SSID 2 : HUAWEI Mate 10 lite
        Network type            : Infrastructure
        Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
        Encryption              : CCMP 
        BSSID 1                 : 1c:15:1f:3f:87:f9
             Signal             : 82%  
             Radio type         : 802.11n
             Channel            : 11 
             Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
             Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54'''

res = []
for i in A.split("\n"):
    if ":" in i:
        val = i.split(" : ")[-1]
        print val.strip()
        res.append(val.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Wi-Fi 2
Rezalitchderk
Infrastructure
WPA2-Personal
CCMP
d1
91%
802.11n
11
1 2 5.5 11
6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
HUAWEI Mate 10 lite
Infrastructure
WPA2-Personal
CCMP
1c:15:1f:3f:87:f9
82%
802.11n
11
1 2 5.5 11
6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

Comment: `re.findall(r':(.*)', A)` will give you the same result.

Comment: @TheIdealis; I am just showing a way to do it without using regex and just string methods.

Comment: Hi, @Rakesh thank you this a veny good wya but the thing is for the bssid is in hexa so it is like this : ec:9b:f3:b4:bb:09 so the only thing retrieved is 09 everything before it is discarded but seems to be working the regex expression `(r':(.*)', A)` . I'll keep trying and see if I get the correct order.

Comment: @AitZaid; That can be fixed by changing the split method. Updated solution now.

Comment: @AitZaid; Changing i.split(" : ") to i.split("  :  ") fixes the problem

Comment: @Rakesh thank you it works with your methode, and also the one with regex: `(r':(.*)', A)`  works perfectly thank you for your answers guys.